# Operators not inserting in the stack in C while trying to convert an infix expression to a postfix one

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am trying to implement an **infix-to-postfix** conversion program. On executing the code I get to see only alpha-numeric characters.  Arithmetic operators are not printing. Upon debugging, I found the operators are not inserting in the stack. I couldn't find out the reason behind this.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 50

char st[MAX];
int top = -1;
void push(char);
char pop();
int priority(char);

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  char x,s[50];
  printf("Enter infix expression: ");
  gets(s);
  while(s[i]!='\0')
  {
    if(isalnum(s[i]))
      printf("%c",s[i]);
    else if(s[i] == '(')
      push(s[i]);
    else if(s[i] == ')')
    {
      while((x=pop())!='(')
              printf("%c",x);
    }
    else
    {
      while(priority(st[top])>=priority(s[i]))
        printf("%c",pop());
      push(st[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  while(top!=-1)
    printf("%c",pop());
}

void push(char x)
{
  st[++top] = x;
}

char pop()
{
  if(top == -1)
    return -1;
  else
    return (st[top--]);
}

int priority(char x)
{
  if(x == '(')
      return 0;
  if(x == '+' || x == '-')
    return 1;
  if(x == '*' || x == '/' || x == '%')
    return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly detected on your debugging session, you don't see operators in your *postfix* expression because you never `push()` them to your stack.

In fact

- in the first `if` you check for alphanumeric characters
- in the following `else if` you check for opening parenthesis
- in the second `else if` you check for closing parenthesis
- in the final else you manage `pop`s from stack... **but you didn't push anything**! <sup>(1)</sup>

---

What you need to fix is the last `else`, where you have at least two distinct problems:

1. You access `st[top]` without checking `top` value. You need to manage the case in which `top = -1`, that would lead to out of bounds access of the stack array and to undefined behavior. I think that in that scenario you just need to push the operator
2. You push in the stack `st[i]`. Probably you meant `s[i]`

In this way the while analysing the expression becomes

```
  while(s[i]!='\0')
  {
    if(isalnum(s[i]))
      printf("%c ",s[i]);
    else if(s[i] == '(' )
      push(s[i]);
    else if(s[i] == ')')
    {
      while((x=pop())!='(')
              printf("%c ",x);
    }
    else
    {
      if( top != -1 )
      {
        while(priority(st[top])>=priority(s[i]))
          printf("%c ",pop());
      }
      push(s[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
```

Input:

```
4*6+3
```

Output:

```
4 6 * 3 +
```

(I added a further space after each `%c` in `printf`s in order to improve output readability).

---

**Note**: You still have to fix some problems in operators priority management.